# Live Paintings Recognition with Camera Flutter App

Tags: flutter, machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection, google-mlkit

I am developing an application with flutter and I would need to implement the possibility of using the smartphone camera to recognize some paintings live (from a finished set) and show some pop up button on the screen that perhaps redirects to a web page where you describes the painting.
Searching a bit online, a first solution would be to use a machine learning live object recognition model but it seems a little too complicated to me. My question therefore is: is there a simpler way considering that the set of paintings to be recognized is small and indeed finite?
A thousand thanks

I looked at this package but it seemed a bit too complicated https://pub.dev/packages/google_mlkit_object_detection

Comment: image recognition is simply a very very complicated topic. I don't think there's an easy way

Comment: Not sure about your exact use case, if it is for some museum guide tool, I have seen apps like scanning a QR code near each painting, or just manually type in a four digit code, to redirect to the matching web page.

Comment: Yes it is for a sort of museum guide, but unfortunately can't use qr code. I am trying to implement the package that I mentioned, hope to find a ia model that can recognize paintings.